# What are good *on-topic* basic questions about a destination?

Tags: discussion, scope

For example, I know next to nothing about **Hawaii**, other than the pictures I see are beautiful and someday I'd like to plan a vacation there.

I'm almost certain that very general questions are unsuitable:

- How to plan my vacation to Hawaii? (**Overly broad**)
- What are the best things to do in Hawaii? (**Not constructive**)

However, I also am *almost* certain that **travel.stackexchange.com** is an excellent place for me to become informed, since it will hopefully be made up of experts on all types of travel topics.  What are some good examples of questions I can ask?

Answer (score 9):

Some ideas for how to come up with questions for your vacation:

- What do **you** like to do when you travel?  Ask if those activities can be found at your destination.
- Ask for activities that are **unique** to your destination.
- Are you travelling with family/children/elderly/etc.?  Ask about lodging or activities in the area that have special accommodations.
- Transportation questions are popular here.  Perhaps you were wondering if you should rent a car or rely on public transportation at your destination.
- Ask about local customs that might come up during your stay (tipping, exchanging greetings, Sharia law*, etc.).

<sub>* obviously, this one won't be an issue in Hawaii, but for the purposes of making this list a little more broadly-applicable....</sub>

Comment: +1 for **unique** activities